# Unable to create Excel macros on particular machine (possible Windows Group Policy issue?)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Windows 2003 Server box with Excel 2010 installed, upon which I am unable to create new or execute existing macros in spreadsheets. Note: this machine is in a Windows Domain (and I am not getting much help from the network folks here.)

**I can and have edited the macro security levels within Excel** (File, Options, Trust Center, Macro Settings --> Enable All Macros) but despite this, when I try to:

1. Open a spreadsheet with macros, I get an exception "Excel found unreadable content...." which goes on to refer to the VBA macros within the spreadsheet
2. Create a new macro **in a brand new spreadsheet created on this machine**, all the toolbar buttons providing access to the VBA editor are disabled.

Could this be a Group Policy setting that allows me to edit the macro security settings, but overrides these settings and prevents me from actually creating, editing, or executing VBA macros?  (If so, does anyone happen to know **which** group policy setting I should be looking for?)

I've run rsop.msc (Resultant Set of Policy) on the machine and looked through every single thing under both Computer Configuration and User Configuration, but I don't see anything related to Excel (or Office) Security/Macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem was that Visual Basic for Applications hadn't been installed when Excel itself was installed.

(As usual, Microsoft could do a much better job of alerting the user to this unusual configuration, but what can you do.)